# NSOutlineView strange padding is cropping a badge

Tags: cocoa, nsoutlineview

I created a view-based `NSOutlineView` with an image and a badge (an inline button). Although the custom cell is wide enough, I have the following problem:

[image]

So there is a strange margin from the right which overlays my badge (the NSOutlineView is embedded in a ScrollView and this in a SplitView).

Any ideas, how I can remove this margin / overlay?

Comment: possibly the scroll bar...

Comment: I also thought about that. I disabled the vertical scrollbar, didn't help

Comment: No one any idea? Also every other view (textfields for example) inside of the outlineview are cropped. You also can see this effect in Mac OS Finder or Mail and so on. I suppose, that it really has to do sth with the scrollbar. The cells inside of the outlineview are automatically resized a little bit smaller than the outlineview itself. By manually increasing the width of a cell in the IB the text is not cropped, but than my badge will not respond any more to the autosizing (yes I still use this and not autolayout ;))

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my last comment brought me the answer ;)
As far as I can see, it's really a problem with the scrollbar, no matter if it's hidden or not. I think it's a relict of older OS X versions, where the scrollbars were permanently shown. When you resize the outlineview (embedded in a scrollview and this embedded in a splitview), the width of the cells automatically will always become a little bit smaller than the width of the outlineview itself (probably because the NSScrollView code thinks, it has to adjust because of the scrollbar).

Therefore I subclassed NSTableCellView (I'm using a viewbased outlineview) and added this:

```
- (void)setFrameSize:(NSSize)newSize {
    //resize the textframe, so that it will not be cropped too early with "..."
    NSRect textFrame = self.textField.frame;
    textFrame.size.width = newSize.width;
    self.textField.frame = textFrame;

    //increase the size of the whole cell
    newSize.width = newSize.width + 10.0;

    [super setFrameSize:newSize];
}
```

You also have to increase the width of the textframe, because - as you can see in Finder or Mail etc. - the text of the cell is very early cropped (with "..."). By increasing it's width, this problem is also solved.

I hope, this description is nearly understandable ;)